# Forward container port set by external service at runtime

Tags: docker

I have a service running in a container on host1. When starting the service it calls out to a "master" service on host2 which tells it to bind to on an arbitrarily assigned port.

Host2 (or other hosts in the cluster) has/have no visibility through to the port bound to the container's private address on host1.  Using `docker run -p` only forwards ports known at image run time.

How would I go about forwarding incoming host connections to this container port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing the host network setup, rather than using NAT through a bridge, solves this problem.

`docker run --net="host" ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could run a proxy on your host that can be notified by the container after it receives the port from the master service, and which will then set up the necessary port forwarding.

Something like [vulcand](https://github.com/mailgun/vulcand), which is an `etcd` backed proxy, might fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately this is a little too complex an architecture for the ROS-based robot I am building. Using ``` run --net="host"``` appears to be doing what I need.